# HTML Form broken

Tags: html

Why does this not render properly (the value does not show)

```
<head>
<style>
.texta {  
  color: #CDCBCB;  
  background-color: #FFFFFF;  
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  font-style:italic
}  
</style>
</head>

<body>
<textarea name="comments" value="Message (required)" cols="40" rows="6" onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" class="texta"></textarea>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value for textarea must be between the textarea tags:

```
<textarea ...>Message (required)</textarea>
```

So it would be:

```
<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="6" onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" class="texta">Message (required)</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value must be between the opening and closing tags of the text area

```
<textarea name="comments cols="40" rows="6" onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" class="texta">Message (required)</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to wrap with form-tag:

```
<form ...><textarea ...>Message (required)</textarea></form>
```